# Laravel Query -> FIRST();

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am struggling with a query! In my SQL Server I put `first();` instead of `get();` and I get the last result so in **LARAVEL 4.2** I get an error. Do you have any advice? Is there a different way to do this? I will give you the code in case you need more information.
Thank you for your time!

```
$users = DB::table('Home_Students')
            ->select('home_firstname','home_lastname','LogSt_data','LogSt_date')
            ->join('Home_LogStudents','Home_LogStudents.LogSt_studid','=','Home_Students.home_id')
            ->join('LessonUnitSections','LessonUnitSections.leuns_ID','=','Home_LogStudents.LogSt_sectionID')
            ->join('LessonUnits','LessonUnits.leun_ID','=','LessonUnitSections.leuns_LessonUnitID')
            ->where('Home_LogStudents.LogSt_action','=',225)
            ->where('Home_LogStudents.LogSt_data','<>',0)
            ->where('Home_LogStudents.LogSt_sectionID','=',$id)
            ->orderBy('LogSt_date','home_firstname')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `orderBy desc` to the query, that should solve your problem.

For example, instead of:

```
->orderBy('LogSt_date','home_firstname')
```

Use this:

```
->orderBy('LogSt_date', 'desc')->orderBy('home_firstname', 'desc')
```

Also, if you do not get error message using `get()`, try to use `->take(1)->get()` instead of `->first()`

Comment: thanks a lot i will keep that in mind for next use its usefull , but in my case didnt worked i get "THE" error :** Trying to get property of non-object **

Comment: Updated my post. Try to use `->take(1)->get()` or `->take(1)->skip(0)->get()` instead of `first()`.

Comment: it gave me the first result but i need for each LogSt_studid any advice on that ?

Comment: I didn't understand what you did mean by 'i need for each LogSt_studid', can you explain this please?

Comment: ('home_firstname','home_lastname','LogSt_data','LogSt_date')  i want to take these from the Home_LogStudents and Home_Students tables  for each LessonUnit ....so i get them , but they are for every STUDENT= LoSt_studid     3 or 4 results i want the last result

Comment: is there is a way to show the last result ->take(1)->get(); but for each student id ?